# Items not aligning properly in CSS container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practicing JavaScript and CSS by following a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFWbAj40JrQ&list=PLDlWc9AfQBfZIkdVaOQXi1tizJeNJipEx).

[Here](https://github.com/jamesqquick/Build-A-Quiz-App-With-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript/blob/master/1.%20Create%20Home%20Page%20and%20Application%20Styling/app.css) is a link to the GitHub repo, where the script is found.

I typed the entire code by hand, so that I could get more familiar with it. And when opening `index.html` in my browser, the content is displayed at the very bottom and very right, rather than being centered as it should. I thought maybe I had a typo, so I copied and pasted the entire code from GitHub and refreshed it, still no change. What could I be doing wrong?
Could the issue lie in index, rather than the script?

Here is my code:

```css
:root {
  background-color: #ecf5ff;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.4rem;
  color: #56a5eb;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

h1 > span {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* UTILITIES */

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > * {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-center {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* BUTTONS */
.btn {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  width: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.1rem solid #56a5eb;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #56a5eb;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  transition: transform 150ms;
}

.btn[disabled]:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widh=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Quick Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container"></div>
      <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column"></div>
        <h1>Oberlingual</h1>
        <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
        <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High scores</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Html code has 2 mistakes.
2 div elements don't have any child elements because you closed each element at the wrong position.
This code will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widh=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Quick Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
        <h1>Oberlingual</h1>
        <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
        <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High scores</a>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got confused with `</div>` closing tags. Here's your mistake:

```
<div class="container"></div>
      <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column"></div>
...
```

This way, you are not wrapping internal content in parent containers - `div` tags.

You need to close the `div` in sequence.

This is how you need to do it, and your code will work:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
  <h1>Oberlingual</h1>
  <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
  <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High scores</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Run this snippet to check here:

```css
:root {
  background-color: #ecf5ff;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.4rem;
  color: #56a5eb;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

h1 > span {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* UTILITIES */

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > * {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-center {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* BUTTONS */
.btn {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  width: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.1rem solid #56a5eb;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #56a5eb;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  transition: transform 150ms;
}

.btn[disabled]:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widh=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Quick Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
     <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
      <h1>Oberlingual</h1>
      <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High scores</a>
     </div>
    </div> 
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @BenjaminNüssli, No problems :) We are always happy to help here. If you have any questions, please let me know. Good coding to you.